# Encoding Task to run on a specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, supersocket.net

I've updated an old project that was using SuperSocket to connect to old c++ servers. With the latest version (from 0.7.0 => 0.8.0.8) I got en exception when trying to reconnect (It says that the socket was opened on a different thread) I would like to have a class that enqueues tasks (First connection and reconnection) and runs them on a specific Thread.

I've seen [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/a-taskscheduler-that-always-run-tasks-in-a-specific-thread) approach but when I try to run the task created as got an exception

> ExecuteTask may not be called for a task which was previously queued to a different TaskScheduler.

Here's the class I've taken from the link above

```
public class SameThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    #region publics
    public SameThreadTaskScheduler(string name)
    {
        scheduledTasks = new Queue<Task>();
        threadName = name;
    }
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (scheduledTasks)
        {
            quit = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(scheduledTasks);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region protected overrides
    protected override IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        lock (scheduledTasks)
        {
            return scheduledTasks.ToList();
        }
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        if (myThread == null)
            myThread = StartThread(threadName);
        if (!myThread.IsAlive)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("My thread is not alive, so this object has been disposed!");
        lock (scheduledTasks)
        {
            scheduledTasks.Enqueue(task);
            Monitor.PulseAll(scheduledTasks);
        }
    }

    public void Queue(Task task)
    {
        QueueTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool task_was_previously_queued)
    {
        return false;
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly Queue<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> scheduledTasks;
    private Thread myThread;
    private readonly string threadName;
    private bool quit;

    private Thread StartThread(string name)
    {
        var t = new Thread(MyThread) { Name = name };
        using (var start = new Barrier(2))
        {
            t.Start(start);
            ReachBarrier(start);
        }
        return t;
    }

    private void MyThread(object o)
    {
        Task tsk;
        lock (scheduledTasks)
        {
            //When reaches the barrier, we know it holds the lock.
            //
            //So there is no Pulse call can trigger until
            //this thread starts to wait for signals.
            //
            //It is important not to call StartThread within a lock.
            //Otherwise, deadlock!
            ReachBarrier(o as Barrier);
            tsk = WaitAndDequeueTask();
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            if (tsk == null)
                break;
            TryExecuteTask(tsk);
            lock (scheduledTasks)
            {
                tsk = WaitAndDequeueTask();
            }
        }
    }

    private Task WaitAndDequeueTask()
    {
        while (!scheduledTasks.Any() && !quit)
            Monitor.Wait(scheduledTasks);
        return quit ? null : scheduledTasks.Dequeue();
    }

    private static void ReachBarrier(Barrier b)
    {
        if (b != null)
            b.SignalAndWait();
    }
}
```

Here's how I call the task

```
public void RegisterServers()
{
    sameThreadTaskScheduler.Queue(new Task(() =>
    {
        ...something
    }));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `Task.Start(TaskScheduler)`, or `Task.Factory.StartNew` with your task scheduler, instead of this public `Queue` method.

Answer (score 2):

You must start a task to bind it to a `TaskScheduler`.  In your code, you're manually queuing the task, doing it the other way around, so the task doesn't get bound to your task scheduler (or any at all), and `TryExecuteTask` will fail with that error.  The description is rather cryptic, as any actual `TaskScheduler` is different from `null`.

For a task that you created without running, there are the overloads of [`Task.RunSynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Task.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.start(v=vs.110).aspx) that take a `TaskScheduler`.

For a task that starts running automatically, there are the overloads of [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TaskFactory<TResult>.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321434(v=vs.110).aspx) that take a `TaskScheduler`.

For continuation tasks, there are the overloads of [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Task<TResult>.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321274(v=vs.110).aspx), [`TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenany(v=vs.110).aspx) that take a `TaskScheduler`.

The overloads that don't take a task scheduler are equivalent to specifying [`TaskScheduler.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current(v=vs.110).aspx).  In the case of `TaskFactory`, this is true for the default [`Task.Factory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.factory(v=vs.110).aspx) or one created without a task scheduler at the time that the factory's method is called, otherwise the factory's task scheduler is used.

---

Contrast with the overloads of the newer [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx), which always use [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default(v=vs.110).aspx).  According to most experienced folks, the thread-pool scheduler is desired more often as the default than `TaskScheduler.Current` which may be thread-bound, but it was too late to change the contract for the existing APIs.